# file_get_contents showing null string for google captcha API

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha

When I hit my following url on chrome location bar, it is showing result in JSON.

[This is the URL](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LeUrysUAAAAAJyGCVjEuyZnt3GpL6LVZbxIWZBH&response=03AJz9lvS160eXqK__KUmZMrlUBCD0gRraO7D3bjvNPbagXdeof3a_BJTllnwUGrgJLaqrMGEplypagyJB2iEDNsJLbkrgTgVjVjKS0TSyn3gEBUcA8wnGI-ccAPUbOwWP6V4REZiAna62mZIpEHBf5FB8u12642JS7ArLzMkwXRlkaJiqTMm6XK0O-eC287ld0VKtmF7OTqZuZhS8iuhabMIxcuNsBDI54fVXU313SgfYG9tb9fQQ5G4_0nAsOlaU3d0AsjVt0q3qYMC7rqynDjTRJtzRdrB-KEYaEND4leBapAGeYfBkfEXp6IZdn2LACvSqaEAUehNHD7DYZZFv4sWXArcUp-D9JzpzG56KSUYftoYYt5H0RcJIb6Jholwihw8_Npx_png91nlwD9sCBVRrB5yTY4sQT3JDNyhz2HcSSsvx6rOaOJ69_TvO5FHzm1pOrzpVpBvM&remoteip=103.68.9.199)

But when I try to parse this using `file_get_contents($url);`
It doesn't print anything. I tried `file_get_Contents` for different url, it is working properly for my other url.

Please suggest where am I getting wrong.

Thank You

Comment: Your recaptcha key is included in that link. You might want to change your credentials...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per given in [document](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify), its a `POST` request.

Here the cURL solution for recaptcha

```
$captcha = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
    $data = array(
        'secret' => RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
        'response' => $captcha
    );

    $verify = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $jsonresponse = curl_exec($verify);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hey jagad89, 
Thank you, this curl is working for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you look at using CURL instead of file_get_content(). But here incase you need it really bad

```
<?php
// <= PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents(<INSERT_URL>, true);
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents(<INSERT_URL>, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. I have used curl also. but same issue, doesn't return anything.
$handle = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   $response = curl_exec($handle);
   $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   echo $httpCode;
   curl_close($handle);

Comment: $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($response);   
   echo '<br />DDDDDD: '; var_dump($response); exit;

Comment: Have you checked whether CURL is installed on the server?  return function_exists('curl_version');

Comment: Yes, I am using 7.20.0